# Several JSP pages and requestURI

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, tiles

I use Apache Tiles to unite multiple jsp pages.What I want is to get the URI of the request that came from web client (from browser). However, when in my jsp page I use

```
${pageContext.request.requestURI}
```

I get not web client uri but the local path of the jsp file. For example when web user enters `http://company.com/something/` (I want to get `/something/`) I get `/jsp/articles/index.jsp`.

I tried requestScope.request.requestURI but it returns empty string. How can I get web client request URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question,you said when you enter "http://company.com/something/" in the browser,you get `/jsp/articles/index.jsp` in JSP,it seems your original request has been forwarded to new one. You can try below to get the orginal URI in JSP page.

```
<% String originalUri = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"); %>
```